# Hadoop Streaming , Unable to run jar from bash file

Tags: bash, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I need to run my mapper and reducer functions which are two runnable jars using hadoop streaming. I have written to bash scripts which run these jar files.
I am using following command for my hadoop streaming

```
bin/hadoop jar contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.1.1.jar \
   -D stream.non.zero.exit.is.failure=false -file /home/abhinav/mapper.jar \
   -file /home/abhinav/reducer.jar -mapper "./mapper.sh | sort -k1,1" \
   -reducer "reducer.sh" -file /home/abhinav/mapper.sh -file /home/abhinav/reducer.sh  \
    -input /home/abhinav/stemp/dfs/name/input.txt -output /home/abhinav/stemp/dfs/name/op30
```

Here is what my mapper.sh looks like

```
java -jar mapper.jar
```

I am getting following error in my task logs

```
Unable to access jarfile mapper.jar
```

I dont understand the reason why my mapper.jar is not accessible on cluster.

Can some one please help.

Following are the logs

```
013-08-21 11:41:18,636 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
2013-08-21 11:41:18,760 INFO org.apache.hadoop.filecache.TrackerDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /home/abhinav/stemp/mapred/local/taskTracker/abhinav/jobcache/job_201308211117_0008/jars/reducer.sh <- /home/abhinav/stemp/mapred/local/taskTracker/abhinav/jobcache/job_201308211117_0008/attempt_201308211117_0008_m_000000_0/work/reducer.sh
2013-08-21 11:41:18,770 INFO org.apache.hadoop.filecache.TrackerDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /home/abhinav/stemp/mapred/local/taskTracker/abhinav/jobcache/job_201308211117_0008/jars/job.jar <- /home/abhinav/stemp/mapred/local/taskTracker/abhinav/jobcache/job_201308211117_0008/attempt_201308211117_0008_m_000000_0/work/job.jar
2013-08-21 11:41:18,772 INFO org.apache.hadoop.filecache.TrackerDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /home/abhinav/stemp/mapred/local/taskTracker/abhinav/jobcache/job_201308211117_0008/jars/.job.jar.crc <- /home/abhinav/stemp/mapred/local/taskTracker/abhinav/jobcache/job_201308211117_0008/attempt_201308211117_0008_m_000000_0/work/.job.jar.crc
2013-08-21 11:41:18,776 INFO org.apache.hadoop.filecache.TrackerDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /home/abhinav/stemp/mapred/local/taskTracker/abhinav/jobcache/job_201308211117_0008/jars/lib <- /home/abhinav/stemp/mapred/local/taskTracker/abhinav/jobcache/job_201308211117_0008/attempt_201308211117_0008_m_000000_0/work/lib
2013-08-21 11:41:18,779 INFO org.apache.hadoop.filecache.TrackerDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /home/abhinav/stemp/mapred/local/taskTracker/abhinav/jobcache/job_201308211117_0008/jars/META-INF <- /home/abhinav/stemp/mapred/local/taskTracker/abhinav/jobcache/job_201308211117_0008/attempt_201308211117_0008_m_000000_0/work/META-INF
2013-08-21 11:41:18,783 INFO org.apache.hadoop.filecache.TrackerDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /home/abhinav/stemp/mapred/local/taskTracker/abhinav/jobcache/job_201308211117_0008/jars/org <- /home/abhinav/stemp/mapred/local/taskTracker/abhinav/jobcache/job_201308211117_0008/attempt_201308211117_0008_m_000000_0/work/org
2013-08-21 11:41:18,788 INFO org.apache.hadoop.filecache.TrackerDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /home/abhinav/stemp/mapred/local/taskTracker/abhinav/jobcache/job_201308211117_0008/jars/mapper.sh <- /home/abhinav/stemp/mapred/local/taskTracker/abhinav/jobcache/job_201308211117_0008/attempt_201308211117_0008_m_000000_0/work/mapper.sh
2013-08-21 11:41:19,050 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists!
2013-08-21 11:41:19,218 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ProcessTree: setsid exited with exit code 0
2013-08-21 11:41:19,226 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@136a1a1
2013-08-21 11:41:19,351 WARN org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
2013-08-21 11:41:19,361 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: numReduceTasks: 1
2013-08-21 11:41:19,373 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
2013-08-21 11:41:21,294 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
2013-08-21 11:41:21,294 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
2013-08-21 11:41:21,367 INFO org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: PipeMapRed exec [/home/abhinav/stemp/mapred/local/taskTracker/abhinav/jobcache/job_201308211117_0008/attempt_201308211117_0008_m_000000_0/work/./mapper.sh]
2013-08-21 11:41:21,412 INFO org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: MRErrorThread done
2013-08-21 11:41:21,414 INFO org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: R/W/S=1/0/0 in:NA [rec/s] out:NA [rec/s]
2013-08-21 11:41:21,415 WARN org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:569)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:135)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:436)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:372)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)

2013-08-21 11:41:21,416 INFO org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess exited with code 1 in org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed
2013-08-21 11:41:21,416 INFO org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: mapRedFinished
2013-08-21 11:41:21,416 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
2013-08-21 11:41:21,423 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task: Task:attempt_201308211117_0008_m_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of commiting
2013-08-21 11:41:21,592 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_201308211117_0008_m_000000_0' done.
2013-08-21 11:41:21,632 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskLogsTruncater: Initializing logs' truncater with mapRetainSize=-1 and reduceRetainSize=-1
2013-08-21 11:41:21,909 INFO org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO: Initialized cache for UID to User mapping with a cache timeout of 14400 seconds.
2013-08-21 11:41:21,909 INFO org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO: Got UserName abhinav for UID 1000 from the native implementation
```

Comment: Is it a permissions issue? Is mapper.jar owned by a different user / group? could you do ls -lta on the dir that contains mapper.jar ?

Comment: On my machine where mapper.jar is present I have done chmod 777. Also I am running hadoop on same machine, under same username. So I dont think its a permission issue.

Comment: If you swap these two files does it complain about not being able to find reducer? I am curious if it is simply complaning about every file or if it something specific to mapper.jar. -file /home/abhinav/mapper.jar -file /home/abhinav/reducer.jar Also, could you be dealing with a 32bit vs 64bit ism? I know that there are several apps that will say that it can't find the file if it is a 64 bit app trying to launch a 32bit binary.

Comment: It is complaining only about mapper.jar and reducer.jar. It is able to find the mapper.sh and reducer.sh, as these scripts run the jar files. I am not able to understand, why these files are not accessible. Shouldn't all the files which we send using -file option get copied in same directory. Also can you tell is there a way to find the job jar which is being created contains the jar files

Comment: Try using -libjars mapper.jar -> Be sure to place the generic options before the streaming options